# parse-server / Node.js / Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server, heroku-cli

I am having these warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated parse-server-fs-adapter@1.0.1: use @parse/fs-files-adapter
npm WARN deprecated parse-server-push-adapter@2.0.2: use @parse/push-adapter
npm WARN deprecated parse-server-s3-adapter@1.2.0: use @parse/s3-files-adapter
npm WARN deprecated parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter@1.0.1: use @parse/simple-mailgun-adapter
```

when I run this command:

```
npm install
```

For information here are the version of `npm` and `node` I have:

```
$ npm --version
3.10.10
$ node --version
v6.11.2
```

Does anyone know what the way to get rid of the above warnings is?

Comment: You get this a lot because third party packages don't always update their dependencies 

Comment: Does that mean, there is nothing I can do about it?

Comment: Probably not. You'll find a lot of npm packages that spit out this kind of stuff 

Comment: @mrstebo, next time you blame developers on not maintaining their projects, it would be nice that you get informed. Also, the notice is clear that a user having those direct dependencies should use the mentioned package

Comment: @flovilmart the only reason I mentioned that is because I wasn't sure if he was getting those issues because the OP is using a library that uses parse-server, or whether they were using it directly.

Comment: OP? (Official Package??) Since these warnings do not seem to be an issue. I reformulated the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466767/git-push-heroku-master-not-working hoping somebody can bring some help.

Answer (score 0):

It’s actually because we moved our official adapters into @parse organization on NPM!

You can safely ignore those for now, parse-server will have those dependencies updates on the next release

Comment: You can update to 2.7.0 and those warnings should disappear!