# -- git push heroku master -- not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server, heroku-cli

I am having trouble running the "*git push heroku master*" command, after cloning  https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example.git locally and making some customization.

Here is part of the trace:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 302 bytes | 302.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  >=4.3
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version >=4.3...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 9.2.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.5.1
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules (exists - skipping)
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        
remote:        > kerberos@0.0.23 install /tmp/build_d0567......8t5bffc/node_modules/kerberos
remote:        > (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)
remote:        
remote:        module.js:544
remote:        throw err;
remote:        ^
remote:        
remote:        Error: Cannot find module 'nan'
remote:        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
remote:        at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
remote:        at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
remote:        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
remote:        at [eval]:1:1
remote:        at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
remote:        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:38)
remote:        at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
remote:        at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
remote:        at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:470:27)
remote:        gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
remote:        gyp ERR! configure error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_d0567......8t5bffc/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-133-generic
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_d0567......8t5bffc/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_d0567......8t5bffc/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_d0567......8t5bffc/node_modules/kerberos
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
```

And here is what I can see in the logs:

```
 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
 app[web.1]: 
 app[web.1]: > parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app
 app[web.1]: > node index.js
 app[web.1]: 
 app[web.1]:     throw err;
 app[web.1]: module.js:544
 app[web.1]: 
 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './Options'
 app[web.1]:     ^
 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:9:16)
 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script.
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output 
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
 app[web.1]: 
 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-11-24T04_25_51_797Z-debug.log
 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Let me say that I can't find the file 2017-11-24T04_25_51_797Z-debug.log metioned in the log wherever I look.
(Is it supposed to be visible somewhere?)

If anyone knows how to handle this problem, please let me know.
By searching I have found similar issues on the net, but nothing leading to a solution.

Comment: you should first try solving module errors that you are getting else may be dependent on it.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Did you commit all your changes in your master branch? Did you run all the `npm install` with the `--save` option in order to 'persist' the dependency into the `package.json`?

Comment: Parse Server is relatively easy to get up & running, but you need to do a few things in Heroku.  You might find this of use: https://www.udemy.com/parse-server/learn/v4/overview

Comment: If you don't want to pay anything, ignore the Migration from parse.com (thats no longer around), but you might find this of use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp3VRKrnZ2o

Comment: I have done this parser-server setting/migration process a couple of times now (all working) so I know the big picture. It's only that this time I probably did something wrong at some point and messed things up, I am now fighting to fall back on my feet.